# Three20 framework with line-height?

Tags: ios, text, coding-style, three20, css

somebody knows if it's possible to set a specific line-height for three20-styled texts?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to achieve decent line spacing on TTStyledText. It is really very noticeable when you use non-standard fonts at larger sizes. However you can get it working with a **lot** of hacking using TTStyledLayout and categories. Look at internal functions that modify _lineHeight and in particular

```
- (void)inflateLineHeight:(CGFloat)height

- (TTStyledFrame*)addFrameForText:(NSString*)text element:(TTStyledElement*)element ...
```

My version is way too messy to release but if someone had the time to do a clean implementation it would be a great addition to three20 (copy and paste would be a nice-to-have also)

Comment: alright, thank you. will have to think about another solutin.